# Set a Usercontrol as a Datatemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have the following ProductList template snipet

```
<Style x:Key="ProductListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type s:SurfaceListBox }">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static s:SurfaceColors.ListBoxItemBackgroundBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="234" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplateSelector">
            <Setter.Value>
                <sc:ProductListTemplateSelector>
                    <sc:ProductListTemplateSelector.NormalItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"                                
                           Margin="7,0,0,0" 
                           MinWidth="171" MaxWidth="171"                                
                           MinHeight="235" MaxHeight="235">
                                <Image Margin="14,21,21,11" Source="{Binding XPath=@Image}" 
                        Height="149" Width="101" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" 
                         MaxWidth="116"
                         FontSize="12"                 
                         Margin="21,0,21,21"
                         FontFamily="Segoe360" 
                         TextAlignment="Center"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static s:SurfaceColors.ListBoxItemForegroundBrushKey}}"  
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sc:ProductListTemplateSelector.NormalItemTemplate>
```

I need to replace the DataTemplate of this style to be set using my user control like

```
<local:MyUserControl>
```

By keeping only  between  section I did not get my control displayed when my Itemsource is set with a collection of myUserControl

Comment: Have you tried what I've suggested?

Comment: Is your `ItemsSource` a collection of `MyUserControl`, or of some object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I just add the DataTemplate in the `Resources`. This can be `<Window.Resources>` or `<App.Resources>` if the data template is global, or `FrameworkElement.Resources` if the template should only be applied in a specified scope. For example, adding the template to `ListView.Resources` would only apply the template within a specific ListView.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductModel}">
        <local:MyUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

As a side note, your original question leads me to believe that you are binding a ListView to a collection of `MyUserControl` objects. I really wouldn't recommend this, but if this is the case you can use a `ContentControl` in your DataTemplate with it's `Content` bound to your object, and it should display correctly.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding }" />
```

Comment: Hello rachel,What is teh reason you said you would not recommand it ?

Comment: @user930203 You are storing a UI object in memory for every item in your list. It is more efficient to keep your just your data in memory, and allow WPF to draw UI Elements as needed. For example, it would be more efficient to store a list of `Product` data classes in memory and tell WPF to draw the `Product` object using `MyUserControl` as a template, than it would be to store a `ProductUserControl` in memory for every `Product` object. This also allows you to take advantage of WPF's Virtualization, which will re-use existing templates when rendering new items rather than building new items.

Comment: @user930203 If you haven't already, I would highly recommend looking into the MVVM Design Pattern when working with WPF. It is perfectly suited for WPF's binding system, and makes it easy to create and maintain your code. Here's a short introduction to it that I wrote if you're interested: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/

Comment: YEs actually this is what i have done. The item source of my litsbox is bind to a list of MyProductviewModel . Then as an Item template I specify to use myUercontrol bind to each property of MyProductViewModel.Product object. should be  ok like this right ?

Comment: @user930203 Sure that'll work, although if you don't actually need any additional functionality of the `ProductViewModel`, you can bind directly to a list of `ProductModel` objects. Also, I'd recommend using an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of a `List<T>` since it will automatically notify the UI when the collection changes.